# AutoMapper: ProjectTo does not work when called in unit tests

Tags: automapper

I have a simple CQRS app going and everything works as expected, mapping works etc.  I guess the reason its not working is because the automapper I am creating is not being applied to the `ProjectTo` since `ProjectTo` is using the extension methods
I even tried passing the mapper from the test to the queryhandler and changing it to `.ProjectTo<T>(mapper.Configuration)`

It fails with the following

> Message: System.InvalidOperationException : Mapper not initialized. Call Initialize with appropriate configuration. If you are trying to use mapper instances through a container or otherwise, make sure you do not have any calls to the static Mapper.Map methods, and if you're using ProjectTo or UseAsDataSource extension methods, make sure you pass in the appropriate IConfigurationProvider instance.

```
public class GetAnnouncementsQueryHandler : IRequestHandler<GetAnnouncementsQuery, IEnumerable<AnnouncementModel>>
{
    private readonly EventsContext context;

    public GetAnnouncementsQueryHandler(EventsContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<AnnouncementModel>> Handle(GetAnnouncementsQuery request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await context.Announcements
            .Where(a => a.OwnerId == request.OwnerId && !a.IsDeleted)
            .ProjectTo<AnnouncementModel>()
            .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Setup for automapper is done through Autofac for the real code, and for testing, i simply copied the profile and called it in the ctor of the test class

```
    private void SetupMapper()
    {
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(opts =>
        {

            opts.CreateMap<Announcement, AnnouncementModel>();
        });
        mapper = config.CreateMapper(); // Use this mapper to instantiate your class
    }
```

FYI, for the real code, I did not need to specify the mapping since `ProjectTo` didnt seem to need it.  Only way i can get it to work from test is if i stop using `ProjectTo` and rely on manual mapping

Comment: I'm having this same issue. Hoping for an answer soon. A little discouraged since it's been over a month. May revert to using .Select().

Comment: I reverted back to getting the list then applying mapper.Map<> instad of relying on ProjectTo, in some instances I could not get ProjectTo to work for testing projects even though it works otherwise. so automapping manually was the better choice for me